# include directory of git repository into own with full functionality

Tags: git, git-subtree

We have recently decided to split a subproject foo from our main project. We don't want to include all of foo, e.g. all foo-related tests can safely be kept in foo/.

Now, I have got two repositories:

```
main/
   include/folder1
   include/foo/
   Test/

foo/
    include/...
    Test/...
```

and I would like to replace main/include/foo by foo/include. This is possible using `git subtree split`. The problem is that this rewrites history and I am unsure how changes of main/include/foo can be pushed to /foo/include. `git subtree push -P include/foo/ foo` gives horrible results.

Anyone knows how to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the split with `git subtree split ...` as you did but if you want it to be on a separate repository use the `git submodule` to have it as a inner repo managed under a separate repository.

> ***`Submodules`*** ***allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated subdirectory*** of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

---

## ***`git submodule`***

Break your big project to sub projects as you did so far.
Now add each sub project to you main project using :

```
git submodule add <url>
```

Once the projected is added tot your repo you have to init and update it.

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

---

This is an illustration of submodule - project inside another project in which each project is a standalone project.

[image]

---

## ***`git subtree`***

***Git subtree allows you to insert any repository as a sub-directory of another one***

Very similar to `submodule` but the main difference is where your code is managed. In submodules the content is placed inside a separate repo and is managed there which allow you to clone it to many other repos as well.

***`subtree`*** is managing the content as part of the root project and not in a separate project.

Instead of writing down how to set it up and to understand how to use it you can simply read this excellent post which will explain it all.

https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it does not completely answer my question as far as i can see. You can do what you described with git subtree as well (adding an external repository to your repository at a given path). The problem is that I want to bind a folder of an external repository to a folder of my repository. So for example i do not want to include the tests of foo and instead only need the includes.(and if i wanted foo/tests as well, i would rather want to bind them to main/Test/foo)